# Python rookie prob type error mistake

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=input("Enter your first number")
b=input("And your second one")
if a>b:
    if a%b==0:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
else:
    if b%a==0:
        print("YES")
    else :
        print ("NO")
```

So it keeps giving me a TypeError "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
sorry I'm really new to this

Answer (score 0):

This is because `input` function returns a `String` so you need to covert if into an `int` or a `float`, like I have done below.

```
a = int(input("Enter your first number"))
b = int(input("And your second one"))
```

OR

```
a = float(input("Enter your first number"))
b = float(input("And your second one"))
```

This should work now.

To know more about these built-in functions visit:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html